# How get label from function

Tags: c++, .net, windows, winforms, label

I had try to call Form like this.Its ok and work.I use it in another function in loop.So i can update it.Just call and close:

```
OutlookAddIn::MyForm p1;
System::String^ str =gcnew System::String(FullName);
p1.label1->Text = "" + str;
p1.ShowDialog();
```

but I need to update it until loop is work for each. I had found a solution - its call Form in Thread:

```
include <windows.h>
include "Connect.h"
extern int Main();


void  MainThread( )
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD  ThreadId;
    BOOL   Active;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0,
                           (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Main,
                           (void*)&Active, 0, &ThreadId);

    while(Active == TRUE);

    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Main func:

```
#include "MyForm.h"


using namespace OutlookAddIn; 

[STAThreadAttribute]
#define PBM_DELTAPOS            (WM_USER+3)
int Main()
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
auto form = gcnew MyForm();
Application::Run(form);
    return 0 ;

}
```

Now I had a thread that work - and I just call where I need `MyThread();` Also I had remake in my Loop function:

```
    OutlookAddIn::MyForm p1;
    System::String^ bstrArray =gcnew System::String(FullName);
    p1.label1->Text = "" + bstrArray;
```

But now I had problem - every time when loop call:

```
OutlookAddIn::MyForm p1;
```

program go here(in MyForm.cpp):

```
this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 57);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(59, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label1->Text = L"Test";
```

And i had Label = Test.